# Get or filter duplicated lines by column

Tags: bash, text-processing

I have a file with three columns and I would like to get duplicated lines by third column, for example:

```
AAA = 342  
BLABLABLA = 2  
BBBx2 = 23  
1+1 = 2  
KOKOKO= 5  
2x1 = 2
```

The output sould be:

```
BLABLABLA = 2  
1+1 = 2  
2x1 = 2
```

I tried with `sort` and `uniq`, but it deletes the repeated lines and I want to print them.

Answer (score 10):

As long as you're interested in the *last* column, you can do it with `sort` and `uniq`:

```
$ sort -k3n test.txt |  uniq  -f2 -D
1+1 = 2
2x1 = 2
BLABLABLA = 2
```

Here, the sort option `-k3n` causes the file to be sorted starting with the third field, in numeric order; the options to `uniq` are:

```
-f2   Skip the first two fields before checking for uniqueness
-D    Print all the repeated lines
```

Unfortunately, you cannot control the number of fields to be checked for uniqueness. You can use `-w` to specify a number of characters to check, but that will only help if the field you are interested in is fixed-width.

Also, beware of trailing whitespace. It will be included in the text to be checked for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

Use Uniq.

```
uniq -f 3 <file name>
```

Comment: This is wrong. It prints the unique lines and not the duplicate lines.

Comment: Also, `uniq` can only work if the files is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

@rici 's response is correct, but note that `-D` is a GNU extension

Here's an awk solution. It runs in a single pass, but stores the previous line:

```
sort -k3n <file name> | awk 'a[$3]++{ if(a[$3]==2){ print b }; print $0}; {b=$0}'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gawk -F'= ' '{d[$2][a[$2]++]=$0} END{for (i in a) {if (a[i] > 1) for (j in d[i]) {print d[i][j]}}}'
```

Explanation:

For each line ($0) take the second field ($2) separated by '= ' and use this field as a key to a hash 'a' to count occurrences of this field, also use this field as the first dimension key for a two-dimensional hash 'd', and the value of hash 'a' referenced by this field as the second dimension key to store the value of the current line ($). At the end loop through all elements of 'a' with values grater than one (means duplicate) and print corresponding values of 'd'.

NOTE: This one liner does not require sorting, but consumes memory.

Comment: Would you like to provide a sentence or two explaining how this works? You're more likely to get some points for that

Answer (score 0):

If your file is large, sorting and buffering may become a resource problem. For these cases, I would recommend the following two-pass approach:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{c[$NF]++;next} c[$NF]>1' input.txt input.txt
```

This will process your input file twice.

- The first time (when `NR`, the global line counter, is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line counter), we simply increase the count of the last field on the line (array variable `c`, with the last field value as "array index"), and immediately skip execution.
- The second time, we reach the `c[$NF]>1` condition outside of a rule block. `awk` will always print the current line, including all possible modifications made so far, if it encounters a condition that evaluates to `true` outside of a rule block. In this case, it will print the current line if the occurence count for the last field is larger than 1 (i.e. it is a duplicate occurence).

**Note** that this relies on your wanting to filter by the *last* column. You state in your question that it should be the third column, but the line

```
KOKOKO= 5
```

in your example input could be interpreted as having only two columns, depending on how exactly you define a "column".